# Why does replacement {0, 0} /. {a_, -a_} -> c does not work?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

Why does replacement `{0, 0} /. {a_, -a_} -> c` not work? How to make `{0,0}` to match the pattern `{a,-a}`?

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question of "why this does not work?", understand that pattern matching is a *structural* operation. Let's look at your rule in detail:

```
{a_, -a_} -> c // FullForm
```

`Rule[List[Pattern[a, Blank[]], Times[-1, Pattern[a, Blank[]]]], c]`

So, in particular, this pattern is looking for an expression with head `Times` as the second element of a list. The simple number expression `0` does not match that pattern, and so the pair `{0, 0}` does not match the full pattern.

Semantically, what you want (I assume) is a *predicate* that asserts that the two elements are additive inverses of each other. And so, on top of the base pattern of a list with two elements, you can add the Condition or PatternTest that other answers demonstrated.

Alternatively, you could avoid naming the elements explicitly by applying a predicate to the pair itself:

```
{{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {3, -3}, {-4, 4}, {1, 0}} /. {_, _}?(EqualTo[0]@*Total) -> c
```

`{{0, 1}, c, c, c, {1, 0}}`

Or, if you can guarantee that your input is already made up of pairs, then you don't need to check that explicitly:

```
{{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {3, -3}, {-4, 4}, {1, 0}} /. _List?(EqualTo[0]@*Total) -> c
```

`{{0, 1}, c, c, c, {1, 0}}`

Answer (score 5):

```
{{0, 0}, {3, -3}, {-4, 4}} /. {a_, b_} /; a + b == 0 -> c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{0, 0}, {3, -3}, {-4, 4}} /. _?(First@# == -Last@# &) -> c
```

> {c, c, c}